# drawing lines over images does not match coordinates. python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

When I plot points sequentially on an image, they are displayed as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#display in a jupyter notebook
%matplotlib inline 
#make and display data 
image = np.full((50,60,), 0, dtype = 'float32')
image[10:20, 10:20] = .5
image[10,20, 30:40] = .5
plt.plot(15,15, 'y*')
plt.plot(35,15, 'b*')
plt.imshow(image)
```

[image: points plotted on image]

But when I try to plot a line between these two points it appears to use a different axis convention:

```
plt.plot([15,15], [35,15], 'y-')
plt.imshow(image)
```

[image: weird plotting]

If I specify an array of points in the line, it works fine:

```
line_x = np.array(range(15,35))
line_y = np.repeat(15, 20)
plt.plot(line_x, line_y, 'y-')
plt.imshow(image)
```

[image: line points specified]

I guess matplotlib is using different axis conventions for these plotting tasks, but I am confused as to why this would work while plotting sequential points but not when plotting a connecting line between two points?

context: I am performing linescans using skimage.measure.profile_line http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html. You specify the start and stop of the linescan with this function, but I want to demonstrate visually where my line scans are in my images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib **always** uses the same convention,

```
plt.plot(x,y, ...)
```

where `x` is the horizontal coordinate, and `y` is the vertical coordinate. This is independent of whether you plot a line of points.

When you call

```
plt.plot(15,15, 'y*')
plt.plot(35,15, 'b*')
```

the x-coordinate of the first point is `15`, the x-coordinate of the second point is `35`.
While when you call `plt.plot([15,15], [35,15], 'y-')`, both of the x-coordinates of the two points are `15`.
Therefore, having two points

```
x1 = 15; y1 = 15
x2 = 35; y2 = 15
```

you can plot them either by

```
plt.plot(x1,y1, 'y*')
plt.plot(x2,y2, 'b*')
```

or

```
plt.plot([x1,x2], [y1,y2], 'y-')
```